# iText XFAFlattener masking mail id and phone number during flattening

Tags: itext7

I am evaluating itext for one of our requirements, and I see that when the PDF is flattened by the flattener, it is masking the email id and phone number fields.
please see image below:
[email field with and without flattening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjYBu.jpg)

I do not see any documentation of configuration / settings in the XFAFlattener to enable / disable masking of email / phone number fields.

Is there some configuration to enable / disable masking of email / phone fields? Any other reasons why this could occur ?

I was expecting the fields to be visible in the non-flattened and flattened versions.
Tried to check for any configuration settings in XFAFlattener to enable / disable field masking, but did not find any.

Further details:
The input is a PDF with XFA form. The following code is used to flatten the PDF.

```
        XFAFlattener xfaFlattener = new XFAFlattener();

        ByteArrayOutputStream flatbaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024 * 500);
        xfaFlattener.flatten(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), flatbaos);
        PdfDocument doc2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(flatbaos.toByteArray())), new PdfWriter(outFileName));
        addAttachments(attachments, doc2);
        doc2.close();
```